# ffmpeg "Time code of first frame" not making sense

Tags: ffmpeg

I can't seem to make sense of where ffmpeg is coming up with the "Time code of first frame" value.

My original file that I am using.

This video has the general timestamps of the original encoding date (aka the start time of the video the way I understanding it) and a duration of 8 min and 52s

```
$ mediainfo GL0100002_output.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : GL0100002_output.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 93.7 MiB
Duration                                 : 8 min 52 s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 476 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 8 min 52 s
Bit rate                                 : 1 342 kb/s
Width                                    : 848 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.138
Stream size                              : 85.2 MiB (91%)
Title                                    : GoPro AVC  
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42
Color range                              : Full
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 8 min 52 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 129 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 8.16 MiB (9%)
Title                                    : GoPro AAC  
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42

Other
ID                                       : 3
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : QuickTime TC
Duration                                 : 8 min 52 s
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Time code of first frame                 : 15:57:41:15
Time code, striped                       : Yes
Title                                    : GoPro AVC  
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : No
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42
```

Now if I run

`ffmpeg -y -nostdin -v error -ss 00:00:00.042 -i GL0100002_output.mp4 -t 00:00:25.192 -map 0 -map -0:d -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 21 -c:a aac -sn GL0100002_test.DSME_0001.mp4`

I get the following mediainfo

```
$ mediainfo GL0100002_test.DSME_0001.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : GL0100002_test.DSME_0001.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 4.54 MiB
Duration                                 : 25 s 234 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 510 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 25 s 234 ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 376 kb/s
Width                                    : 848 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.141
Stream size                              : 4.14 MiB (91%)
Title                                    : GoPro AVC  
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=2 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=6 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=30 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=21.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Color range                              : Full
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 25 s 214 ms
Duration_LastFrame                       : -3 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 129 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 398 KiB (9%)
Title                                    : GoPro AAC  
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

Other
ID                                       : 3
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : QuickTime TC
Duration                                 : 25 s 234 ms
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Time code of first frame                 : 15:57:41:15
Time code, striped                       : Yes
Title                                    : GoPro AVC  
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : No
```

But what I don't understand is where `Time code of first frame` is coming from. I would expect it would be `00:00:00.042` or even `UTC 2022-02-23 15:18:42` + .042 but appear to be.

```
Time code of first frame                 : 15:57:41:15
```

Is this potentially clobbering together something to get this time that isn't obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time code is stored in a separate time code track and is written by the original authoring app viz. GoPro. This field comes from the professional TV/broadcast practice of storing consecutive timecodes on successive pieces of recording, originally on analogue tapes.

Add `-write_tmcd false` to disable copying it over.

Comment: Do you know what the 15:57:41:15 value indicates? Is it just an absolute value that the GoPro generates that just happens to be close to the wall clock time? Like what is it? Is it a wall clock time?

I'm mainly interested in the  `-ss 00:00:00.042` value making it into the resulting file. I thought that was what the `time code of first frame` meant but obviously that is different. I'm breaking larger video files up and need a way of referencing them back to time (UTC time) and/or know which ones came from which part of the original video.